# How can I validate a custom token (which is not JWT) in ASP .NET Core 2.0 Web API?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api2

In our ASP .NET Core 2.0, Web API, when the user logs in, we generate a GUID and return that to the user after storing it in database. What is the best practice to validate this token when the user submits a request to a controller having Authorize attribute on it.

Should I override AuthorizeAttribute.OnAuthorization and put my custom logic in there ? or is there any other place where I should place my custom logic ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes. You need to write a custom Authorize attribute to suits for your own logic. disadvantage is there will be a DB call for each request.

Comment: Don't write a custom attribute.  The Authorize attribute serves a very important function.  What you need is a custom authorization handler that you add as a service in the Startup.cs file.

Comment: Hi @Brad, can you please provide a link to an example :)

Answer (score 1):

In ASP .NET Core 2.0 you can write you own Middleware to validate token. You can see this video as exapmle - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n0llyujNGw8.

Summarily:
1. Create TokenMiddleware:

```
public class TokenMiddleware
{
    // always should be RequestDelegate in constructor
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    public TokenMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    // always should be defiened Invoke or InvokeAsync with HttpContext and returned Task (You can also inject you services here - for example DataContext)
    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, DataContext dataContext)
    {
        var validKey = true;

        // than you logic to validate token              

        if (!validKey)
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = (int) HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("Invalid Token");
        }
        // if validm than next middleware Invoke
        else
        {
            await _next.Invoke(context);
        }
    }
}

// Extension to IApplicationBuilder (to register you Middleware)
public static class TokenExtensions
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseTokenAuth(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        return builder.UseMiddleware<TokenMiddleware>();
    }
}
```

2. Registred you Middleware in Startup:

app.UseTokenAuth();

Comment: This is great - video link / presentation very helpful in understanding, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Question was made long time ago, but for people that might stumble upon it, here is the way I did it, taking advantage of authentication and authorization middlewares. The question doesn't have details about the way the token is passed in the request but I am assuming a standard Authorization header.

### Create a custom AuthenticationHandler

*MyCustomTokenHandler.cs*

```
public class MyCustomTokenHandler: AuthenticationHandler<AuthenticationSchemeOptions>
{
    public MyCustomTokenHandler(IOptionsMonitor<AuthenticationSchemeOptions> options, ILoggerFactory logger, UrlEncoder encoder, ISystemClock clock) : base(options, logger, encoder, clock)
    {
    }

    protected override async Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
    {
        if (!Request.Headers.ContainsKey("Authorization"))
        {
            return AuthenticateResult.NoResult();
        }
        if (!AuthenticationHeaderValue.TryParse(Request.Headers["Authorization"], out AuthenticationHeaderValue? headerValue))
        {
            return AuthenticateResult.NoResult();
        }
        if (!Scheme.Name.Equals(headerValue.Scheme, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            return AuthenticateResult.NoResult();
        }
        if (headerValue.Parameter == null)
        {
            return AuthenticateResult.NoResult();
        }
        //The token value is in headerValue.Parameter, call your db to verify it and get the user's data

        var claims = new[] { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "username found in db") };
        //set more claims if you want
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, Scheme.Name);
        var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
        var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(principal, Scheme.Name);
        return AuthenticateResult.Success(ticket);
    }
}
```

### Register the handler and enable authorization

*Program.cs*

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication("Bearer").AddScheme<AuthenticationSchemeOptions, MyCustomTokenHandler>("Bearer", null);
//...
var app = builder. Build();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

Most of the code is inspired by this blog post: https://joonasw.net/view/creating-auth-scheme-in-aspnet-core-2